# Can I use both おさまって and おちついて to say "everyone, keep calm?"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

みんな、おちついて
Or
みんな、おさまって

Say there's a earthquake and teacher says to his students "everyone, keep calm." 
How'd he do that in Japanese?

I'm asking here because translators don't explain why they used the word they did and not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural choice is おちついて.

おさまって sounds grandiose and even funny, unless you were saying this to a furious god rather than school kids. Basically, when we want to say "calm down" out aloud to someone, おさまれ／おさまって is almost never used, except for by stereotyped samurais, fictional [chunibyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_anime_and_manga#Ch.C5.ABniby.C5.8D) characters and such.

収まる is relatively more literary, and tends to be used when someone is angry or furious, rather than simply confused.

> - 彼【かれ】の怒【いか】りが収まる。
> - 暴動【ぼうどう】が収【おさ】まる。